# Python DataReader - Update with new information

Tags: python, pandas, datareader

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as wb

tickers = ["MMM",   "ABT",  "ABBV", "ABMD", "ACN",  "ATVI", "ADBE", "AMD",  "AAP",  "AES",  "AFL",  "A",    "APD",  "AKAM", "ALK",  "ALB",  "ARE",  "ALXN", "ALGN", "ALLE", "LNT",  "ALL",  "GOOGL",    "GOOG", "MO",   "AMZN", "AMCR", "AEE",  "AAL",  "AEP",  "AXP",  "AIG",  "AMT",  "AWK",  "AMP",  "ABC",  "AME",  "AMGN", "APH",  "ADI",  "ANSS", "ANTM", "AON",  "AOS",  "APA",  "AAPL", "AMAT", "APTV", "ADM",  "ANET", "AJG",  "AIZ",  "T",    "ATO",  "ADSK", "ADP",  "AZO",  "AVB",  "AVY",  "BKR",  "BLL",  "BAC",  "BK",   "BAX",  "BDX", "BBY",   "BIO",  "BIIB", "BLK",  "BA",   "BKNG", "BWA",  "BXP",  "BSX",  "BMY",  "AVGO", "BR",  "CHRW",  "COG",  "CDNS", "CZR",  "CPB",  "COF",  "CAH",  "KMX",  "CCL",  "CARR", "CTLT", "CAT",  "CBOE", "CBRE", "CDW",  "CE",   "CNC",  "CNP",  "CERN", "CF",   "SCHW", "CHTR", "CVX",  "CMG",  "CB",   "CHD",  "CI",   "CINF", "CTAS", "CSCO", "C",    "CFG",  "CTXS", "CLX",  "CME",  "CMS",  "KO",   "CTSH", "CL",   "CMCSA",    "CMA",  "CAG",  "COP",  "ED",   "STZ",  "COO",  "CPRT", "GLW",  "CTVA", "COST", "CCI",  "CSX",  "CMI",  "CVS",  "DHI",  "DHR",  "DRI",  "DVA",  "DE",   "DAL",  "XRAY", "DVN",  "DXCM", "FANG", "DLR",  "DFS",  "DISCA",    "DISCK",    "DISH", "DG",   "DLTR", "D",    "DPZ",  "DOV",  "DOW",  "DTE",  "DUK",  "DRE",  "DD",   "DXC",  "EMN",  "ETN",  "EBAY", "ECL",  "EIX",  "EW",   "EA",   "EMR",  "ENPH", "ETR",  "EOG",  "EFX",  "EQIX", "EQR",  "ESS",  "EL",   "ETSY", "EVRG", "ES",   "RE",   "EXC",  "EXPE", "EXPD", "EXR",  "XOM",  "FFIV", "FB",   "FAST", "FRT",  "FDX",  "FIS",  "FITB", "FE",   "FRC",  "FISV", "FLT",  "FLIR", "FMC",  "F",    "FTNT", "FTV",  "FBHS", "FOXA", "FOX",  "BEN",  "FCX",  "GPS",  "GRMN", "IT",   "GNRC", "GD",   "GE",   "GIS",  "GM",   "GPC",  "GILD", "GL",   "GPN",  "GS",   "GWW",  "HAL",  "HBI",  "HIG",  "HAS",  "HCA",  "PEAK", "HSIC", "HSY",  "HES",  "HPE",  "HLT",  "HFC",  "HOLX", "HD",   "HON",  "HRL",  "HST",  "HWM",  "HPQ",  "HUM",  "HBAN", "HII",  "IEX",  "IDXX", "INFO", "ITW",  "ILMN", "INCY", "IR",   "INTC", "ICE",  "IBM",  "IP",   "IPG",  "IFF",  "INTU", "ISRG", "IVZ",  "IPGP", "IQV",  "IRM",  "JKHY", "J",    "JBHT", "SJM",  "JNJ",  "JCI",  "JPM",  "JNPR", "KSU",  "K",    "KEY",  "KEYS", "KMB",  "KIM",  "KMI",  "KLAC", "KHC",  "KR",   "LB",   "LHX",  "LH",   "LRCX", "LW",   "LVS",  "LEG",  "LDOS", "LEN",  "LLY",  "LNC",  "LIN",  "LYV",  "LKQ",  "LMT",  "L",    "LOW",  "LUMN", "LYB",  "MTB",  "MRO",  "MPC",  "MKTX", "MAR",  "MMC",  "MLM",  "MAS",  "MA",   "MKC",  "MXIM", "MCD",  "MCK",  "MDT",  "MRK",  "MET",  "MTD",  "MGM",  "MCHP", "MU",   "MSFT", "MAA",  "MHK",  "TAP",  "MDLZ", "MPWR", "MNST", "MCO",  "MS",   "MOS",  "MSI",  "MSCI", "NDAQ", "NTAP", "NFLX", "NWL",  "NEM",  "NWSA", "NWS",  "NEE",  "NLSN", "NKE",  "NI",   "NSC",  "NTRS", "NOC",  "NLOK", "NCLH", "NOV",  "NRG",  "NUE",  "NVDA", "NVR",  "NXPI", "ORLY", "OXY",  "ODFL", "OMC",  "OKE",  "ORCL", "OTIS", "PCAR", "PKG",  "PH",   "PAYX", "PAYC", "PYPL", "PENN", "PNR",  "PBCT", "PEP",  "PKI",  "PRGO", "PFE",  "PM",   "PSX",  "PNW",  "PXD",  "PNC",  "POOL", "PPG",  "PPL",  "PFG",  "PG",   "PGR",  "PLD",  "PRU",  "PEG",  "PSA",  "PHM",  "PVH",  "QRVO", "PWR",  "QCOM", "DGX",  "RL",   "RJF",  "RTX",  "O",    "REG",  "REGN", "RF",   "RSG",  "RMD",  "RHI",  "ROK",  "ROL",  "ROP",  "ROST", "RCL",  "SPGI", "CRM",  "SBAC", "SLB",  "STX",  "SEE",  "SRE",  "NOW",  "SHW",  "SPG",  "SWKS", "SNA",  "SO",   "LUV",  "SWK",  "SBUX", "STT",  "STE",  "SYK",  "SIVB", "SYF",  "SNPS", "SYY",  "TMUS", "TROW", "TTWO", "TPR",  "TGT",  "TEL",  "TDY",  "TFX",  "TER",  "TSLA", "TXN",  "TXT",  "TMO",  "TJX",  "TSCO", "TT",   "TDG",  "TRV",  "TRMB", "TFC",  "TWTR", "TYL",  "TSN",  "UDR",  "ULTA", "USB",  "UAA",  "UA",   "UNP",  "UAL",  "UNH",  "UPS",  "URI",  "UHS",  "UNM",  "VLO",  "VAR",  "VTR",  "VRSN", "VRSK", "VZ",   "VRTX", "VFC",  "VIAC", "VTRS", "V",    "VNO",  "VMC",  "WRB",  "WAB",  "WMT",  "WBA",  "DIS",  "WM",   "WAT",  "WEC",  "WFC",  "WELL", "WST",  "WDC",  "WU",   "WRK",  "WY",   "WHR",  "WMB",  "WLTW", "WYNN", "XEL",  "XLNX", "XYL",  "YUM",  "ZBRA", "ZBH",  "ZION", "ZTS"]

financial_data = pd.DataFrame()
for t in tickers:
    financial_data[t] = wb.DataReader(t, data_source='yahoo', start = '1995-1-1')["Adj Close"]
financial_data.to_excel("Financial Data.xlsx")
```

I am using Datareader to gather some stock info. I am grabbing a lot of info (from 1995 to 2021) and then I export it to Excel. I was wondering if there is a way, let's say tomorrow, to speed up the update of the information, instead of running the whole script on Python from start to bottom, since my goal tomorrow would just be to have a single new line on the whole Excel file. If I just execute the script, it will override the Excel file + add a new line of info. This seems pretty ineffective, and I was wondering if there's a way to "tell the script" I am just looking for tomorrow's info, instead of "telling it" to grab me again the information starting from 1995.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how pandas works, but I would say it does lazy fast loading and this is not very computationally expensive. The costly thing is to operate with each loaded data. Then I think that in your case if the data is ordered by dates in increasing order, it would be enough to have a variable called timestamp_toStart initialized the first time to '1995-1-1' and that after this, after the first execution it is updated to the last value of the last date read. You could save this value in a file and reread it and load it every time you rerun the script.

```
financial_data = pd.DataFrame()
#load timestamp_toStart from the file here 
for t in tickers:
  financial_data[t] = wb.DataReader(t, data_source='yahoo', start = timestamp_toStart)["Adj Close"]
  timestamp = wb.DataReader(t, data_source='yahoo', start = timestamp_toStart)["MMM"] #Not Sure about the correct syntax
timestamp_toStart = timestamp
#Save in a file timestamp_toStart
financial_data.to_excel("Financial Data.xlsx")
```